# Using Parallel Patterns Library (ppl.h)

Tags: c++, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm trying to learn how to use ppl.h in c++ . But I'm not sure what kind of solution I should create in VS2010 to use it. If i create a Win32 Console app without CLR'concurrency' is not recognized and if i create Win32 Console app with CLR i get an error saying

> Concurrency Runtime is not supported when compiling /clr.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ppl.h>
using namespace System;
void BubbleSort(int* input, int n)
{
    concurrency::parallel_for(0,n,[=](int y)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k< n - 1 -y; k++)
        {
            if(input[k]> input[k+1])
            {
                auto temp = input[k+1];
                input[k+1] = input[k];
                input[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Win32 Console Application (no CLR).  Once you `#include <ppl.h>`, the `Concurrency` namespace should be available.  Note that it's [`Concurrency::parallel_for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492819.aspx) (captial "C").

For details, see the [PPL example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx).

Comment: Thanks , was following someone else's guide which had the Concurrency as concurrency

Comment: even the MSDN docs `using namespace concurrency`, which is wrong for me on VS2013 and Windows 10. Capital C works